# TS can't infer return type of simple function

Tags: typescript, function, return, return-type

I feel like I've done this a thousands times and it should work. Why doesn't it?
I am sending string so TS should know a string will come back out, right?

```
export function sayHi(text: string | null) {
  return text ? "Hello" : null
}

const msg: string = sayHi("hi") ////Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=5&ssc=32&pln=1&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAMwK4DsDGMCWEVwM4CGAngBKYAUMoMAXPjFJigOZwA%20cKSANtwJRwA3gCg4cKMBhIouKiHgB%20OACISwXhGVw6XXsIC%20w4Whx54AWzzM6ZxizgBefMTLllAC0zK%20QA)

Comment: It has never worked like that. The function returns `string | null`. If you want to have it return something based on the parameter, then use a [function overload](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads). Note that you can't actually type this function quite correct here because input of an empty string will return `null`. So, unless you know what the exact string is, you won't be able to guarantee the result is definitely a string.

Comment: Maybe you had `strictNullChecks` disabled when you did it the "thousands of times" before...